# Angularjs ng-click inside an isolated scope invokes functions on outter scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I´m using angular.ui tabset directive. I know it´s uses transclude and has an isolated scope, but I don´t understand the following behavior:

If I set a ng-model inside the directive, angular binds it to the directive scope. That´s what I expected, but if an invoke is made using ng-click (inside the directive), the outter scope function is called.

Does anybody could help me understand this please?

```
<html data-ng-app="test">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.2.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div data-ng-controller="Ctrl">
 Outter scope id: {{ $id }}

  <tabset>
    <tab heading="Tab 1">
        <p>Inner scope id: {{ $id }}</p>

        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
        <p>This model is bound on inner scope: {{ name }}</p>

        <p>
          <button data-ng-click="foo()">Invoke Foo</button>
          This button is inside inner scope but invokes foo() on outter scope.
        </p>
    </tab>
  </tabset>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and javascript code:

```
angular.module('test', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Test";

    $scope.foo = function() {
      alert($scope.$id + ' - ' + $scope.name);
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: I still don't get exactly what issue you're having? I put your code into a JSFiddle, and it works as I would expect - when I hit the button I get an alert with "002 - Test2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That works because your child scope inheritance from parent scope.

please see more here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: That was what I missed: "What happens is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works". Thanks for the answer.